# Python. Вычисление квадратного корня из числа размерностью 10^300?

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Пожалуйста, подскажите как можно вычислить квадратный корень из числа размерностью `10^300`?

Функция модуля `math`

```
int(m.sqrt(N))
```

Работает корректно, но не для больших значений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представленный алгоритм работает только для целых чисел. Модуль `math` использоваться в данном случае не может из-за ошибок округления. Также вы можете поискать альтернативные решения, [расширенные комментарии](https://github.com/yuvadm/tiva-c/blob/master/utils/isqrt.c) или [оптимизации](http://www.cc.utah.edu/~nahaj/factoring/isqrt.c.html) используя поисковой запрос [Integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) или isqrt. Пример реализации я взял из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python). Там же есть и на порядки более быстрые реализации с использованием сторонних математических модулей.

```
def isqrt(x):
    """
    Вычисляет квадратный корень любого сколь угожно большего целого числа

    Функция возвращает кортеж (a, r), где a **  2 + r = x
    a - наибольшее целое такое, что a**2 <= x, а r - это остаток
    Если x - идельный квадрат, то остаток равен нулю

    Алгоритм использовался в алгоритме "длиннорукий квадратный корень", описанный по адресу
    http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52656.html

    Tobin Fricke 2014-04-23
    Max Planck Institute for Gravitational Physics
    Hannover, Germany
    """

    N = 0   # Исходные данные на текущей итерации
    a = 0   # Решение на текущей итерации

    # Число будет обработано начиная с MSB, 2 бита за раз
    # MSB - Most significant bit, старший бит, наиболее значимый бит
    L = x.bit_length()
    L += (L % 2)          # Округление до следующего четного

    for i in range(L, -1, -1):

        # Следующие два бита
        n = (x >> (2*i)) & 0b11

        # Проверка на то, можем ли мы уменьшить остаток
        if ((N - a*a) << 2) + n >= (a << 2) + 1:
            b = 1
        else:
            b = 0

        a = (a << 1) | b   # Добавляем следующий бит решения
        N = (N << 2) | n   # Добавляем следующий бит исходных данных

    return a, N-a*a

assert(isqrt(287588743834685763847583454323427 ** 2)[0] == 287588743834685763847583454323427)
#
assert(isqrt(10 ** 300)[0] == 10 ** 150)
#
assert(isqrt(2 ** 1578)[0] == 2 ** 789)


assert(isqrt(2 ** 83470)[0] == 2 ** (83470 // 2))

assert(all(isqrt(i ** 2)[0] == i for i in range(10**5)) is True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Даже без модуля `math` `python` корректно возвращает значения:

```
print(math.sqrt(10 ** 300)) # 1e+150
print((10 ** 300) ** 0.5)   # 1e+150
```

`1e+150` значит, что результат вычислений — 10 в степени 150, и это корректный результат для квадратного корня из `10^300`.

`3.2e-87`  —  "3.2 * 10^-87"

`0.01e+62` —  "0.01 * 10^62"
И т.д.

Просто нужно научиться читать такие числа и всё

Comment: Я подозреваю, что подразумевалось извлечение точного корня. выражение `int(math.sqrt(10**300)) == 10**150` вычислится как False, чего бы не хотелось.

Comment: при попытке вычислить корень из большого числа получаю сообщение об ошибке. OverflowError: int too large to convert to float